# Oozie Workflow to insert 'n' values into a table

Tags: hive, hiveql, oozie

I want to write a hive query and use it in a workflow. The query should take input and insert 'n' values into a table. The catch is that 'n' can be different every time the workflow is run. So is this possible to achieve using hive query?

Comment: Is it like passing `n` as a variable?

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti don't know if it is possible or not. But I solved the problem by passing a single string with comma separated values and then splitting and inserting them into multiple rows.

Comment: Yes passing variable in hive query in oozie possible. Do you want that way?